# What does it mean for a function $f(x)$ to be differentiable at $x_0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers

What does it mean for a function $f(x)$ to be differentiable at $x_0$?

I need this to understand more concepts in real-analysis and calculus.

Thank you.

Comment: It means the limit $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ exists finitely

Comment: Perhaps first tell us what are the domain and range of $f$... I ask because of your tag "multivariable-calculus".

Comment: Calculus not multivariable-calculus... sorry my error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, if x is a point in the domain of a function f, then f is said to be differentiable at x if the derivative f′(x) exists. Intuitively, this means that the graph of f has a non-vertical tangent line at the point (x, f(x)). This also means that the function, at the point x, has no bends, cusps, breaks, or, as mentioned, a vertical tangent.

Comment: Nice point at the end which intuitively links the concept of differentiability and continuity. +1!

Answer (score 3):

That a function $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$ means that the derivative of $f(x)$ evaluated at $x_0$ exists, which means that the following exists: $$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=f'(x_0).$$
**Examples:**

Let $f(x)=x^{-1}$, then $f'(x)=-x^{-2}$. We say $f(x)$ is differentiable at $3$ because $f'(3)=-1/9$ exists. We say $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $0$ since division by zero is undefined and thus $f'(0)$ doesn't exist.

I hope this helps.
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, a function is *differentiable* if it is locally linearly approximable. That means for a given point $x_0$ in the domain of $f$, there is a linear approximation of $f$ near $x_0$. The error of the linear approximation falls to zero as you restrict the approximation to smaller and smaller neighborhoods of the point $x_0$ (that's what "approximable" means).

For functions $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, the graph of the approximating function is a small piece of the tangent to the graph of $f$ at $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

for example

$f(x)=x^2$ is differentiable at $x=0$

but  $f(x)=1/x$ is not differentiable at $x=0$
because  $f'(x)=-1/x^2$

which is not defined at $x=0$